# SQLite3 database insert using variables

Tags: ruby, sqlite

I am writing a script that exports results into a SQLite database. I can not get the code to work when I use variables.

Here is an excerpt:

```
require 'sqlite3'
require 'shodan'

table_name = "#{Date.today.strftime("%B")}#{Time.now.year}_Findings"
db = SQLite3::Database.new "shodan_test.db"
db.execute ("CREATE TABLE #{table_name} (ip string , ports string)")

results = api.host(target)

ip = results["ip_str"].to_s
ports = results["ports"].to_s

db.execute ("insert into #{table_name} (ip, ports) values (#{ip}, #{ports})")
```

The code fails at the last line.  I can remove the variables and the code works. I'm a bit confused since the CREATE TABLE works with a variable.

Comment: When you say "can not get the code to work" and "The code fails", we'd expect there would be some sort of status or error message, or at least a more descriptive statement about *why* it doesn't work. It's really hard to tell what the problem is without those. Please edit your question and add that information in as if you'd originally included it. That helps us help you.

Comment: I'd recommend reading about [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net). It's much better than writing directly to the SQLite API as an ORM, which Sequel is, abstracts your DBM-centric code into more generic code, making it MUCH easier to move to alternate database-types.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're not quoting your strings. The result is that SQLite sees things like

```
insert into ... values (192.168.0.6, whatever is in ports)
```

and that's not valid SQL.

[`SQLite3::Database#execute`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby/SQLite3%2FDatabase%3Aexecute) understands placeholders so you should use them:

```
db.execute("insert into #{table_name} (ip, ports) values (?, ?)", ip, ports)
```

The placeholders (`?`) in the query will be replaced with properly quoted and escaped versions of their values. Using placeholders avoids all the usual quoting and injection problems that plague using string interpolation for SQL.

Also note that I've removed the space between `execute` and `(`. If you put a space there then Ruby thinks your "method calling parentheses" are actually "expression grouping parentheses" and it will complain about not understanding what those commas are doing. If you're only passing one argument (such as in `db.execute ("CREATE ...")`) then it won't matter because the parentheses are effectively ignored but it does matter when there are multiple arguments. In any case, `o.m (arg)` is a bad habit to get into, you should say `o.m(arg)` or leave the parentheses out.

Comment: Exactly, that's how the answer should look like :)